# Subscribe to form field data which needs to be populated from the first item of the array which is fetched from server - Angular

Tags: angular, http, asynchronous

I need to subscribe to a form field's value changes and disable it based on a logic. This form field needs to be populated from the data from API which needs to be stored in an array, and needs to be set to the first item in the array. But subscribing gives `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` even though the value is set only ones. Here is the code:

```
currencyList : string[] = [];
ngOnInit() {
   //form controls are initialized
   this.handleCurrency();
}


handleCurrency(){           
        if(!this.formgroup.get('requestCurrency').value){           
            this.currencyService.fecthCurrencies().subscribe( (data) => {
                this.currencyList = data;
                this.defaultAndDisableCurrency();           
            }, () => {
                //in case API call fails
                this.currencyList.push("EUR");
                this.defaultAndDisableCurrency();
            });                     
        }
        //this.defaultAndDisableCurrency(); I would like to call the function here after API call is complete but this line gets executed without waiting for the call to complete                          
    }

defaultAndDisableCurrency(){
    let cur: any = this.formgroup.get('requestCurrency');       
    cur.valueChanges.subscribe((data)=>{
        if(data === "EUR"){
            cur.disable();
        }
    });
    cur.setValue(this.currencyList[0]);
        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it, but can you try this?  *(I can't test since I don't have your api, sry)*
I used async await function to wait on the api response

```js
currencyList : string[] = [];
ngOnInit() {
   //form controls are initialized
   this.handleCurrency();
}


handleCurrency() {           
        if(!this.formgroup.get('requestCurrency').value){           
            this.currencyService.fecthCurrencies().subscribe( (data) => {
                this.currencyList = data;           
            }, () => {
                //in case API call fails
                this.currencyList.push("EUR");
            }, () => {
                // Put it under the complete to avoid repeating code
                this.defaultAndDisableCurrency(); 
            });                     
        } else {
          // In the "else", because you'll call it if the controls already have value
          this.defaultAndDisableCurrency();    
        }              
    }

async defaultAndDisableCurrency(): Promise<void>{
    let cur: any = this.formgroup.get('requestCurrency');       
    await cur.valueChanges.subscribe((data)=>{
        if(data === "EUR"){
            cur.disable();
        }
    });

    cur.setValue(this.currencyList[0]); // I don't understand what you're doing here     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for the API call to finish, which is the third callback on an observable subscription.

```
currencyList: string[] = [];
ngOnInit() {
    this.handleCurrency();
}

handleCurrency() {
    if (!this.formgroup.get('requestCurrency').value) {
        this.currencyService.fecthCurrencies().subscribe(
            (data) => {
                this.currencyList = data;
                this.defaultAndDisableCurrency();
            },
            (error) => {
                this.currencyList.push('EUR');
                this.defaultAndDisableCurrency();
            },
            (complete) => {
                this.defaultAndDisableCurrency();
            }
        );
    } else {
        this.defaultAndDisableCurrency();
    }
}

defaultAndDisableCurrency() {
    let cur: any = this.formgroup.get('requestCurrency');
    cur.valueChanges.subscribe((data) => {
        if (data === 'EUR') {
            cur.disable();
        }
    });
    cur.setValue(this.currencyList[0]);
}
```